# RuntimeException using Tomcat and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, exception, tomcat

I just cannot get this problem!

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE USER_NAME ='test';'' at line 1
```

Can you please help me? I have no idea, what could be wrong! The syntax is okay, isn't it?

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/onlinebanking");
connection = ds.getConnection();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
resultSetKunden_id = statement.executeQuery(kunde_id);
resultSetKontostand = statement.executeQuery(kontostand);
resultSetTest = statement.executeQuery(test);
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
```

Here's the SQL-Statement:

```
String sql = "select tr.EMPFÄNGER_KONTO_ID, tr.BETRAG " +
"from TRANSAKTION tr, KONTO ko, KUNDE ku " +
"where tr.KONTO_ID = ko.KONTO_ID " +
"and ko.KUNDE_ID = ku.KUNDE_ID " +
"and ku.KUNDE_NAME = '" + username +"' " +
"and ku.KUNDE_PASSWORD = '" + password +"';";

kunde_id = "SELECT kunde_id FROM kunde WHERE KUNDE_NAME ='" + username + "';";
String test = "SELECT * FROM kunde WHERE KUNDE_NAME ='" + username + "';";
kontostand = "Select betrag From Transaktion Where Konto_id = " + kunde_id + "';";
```

(Some words are in german)

Here's the Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Janssen''' at line 1
de.java2enterprise.onlinebanking.HalloWeltServlet.getData(HalloWeltServlet.java:112)
de.java2enterprise.onlinebanking.HalloWeltServlet.doGet(HalloWeltServlet.java:32)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code you use to make the SQL call?

Comment: Don't comment with your code, just edit your question with the codes :D.

Comment: I just customized some varnames, because they are in german

Comment: please show the sql statement as it appears in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would suggest using either a prepared statement or even an ORM framework.**

But to answer your question, you should replace:

```
kontostand = "Select betrag From Transaktion Where Konto_id = '" + kunde_id + "'";
```

with

```
kontostand = "Select betrag From Transaktion Where Konto_id = (" + kunde_id + ")";
                                                              ^                ^
```

Comment: @minimen What is the other exception?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Comment: @minimen Ok this is another problem, it has nothing to do with sql syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Do not put ; (semi  colon ) in your queries .

So your queries will be :

```
String sql = "select tr.EMPFÄNGER_KONTO_ID, tr.BETRAG " +
"from TRANSAKTION tr, KONTO ko, KUNDE ku " +
"where tr.KONTO_ID = ko.KONTO_ID " +
"and ko.KUNDE_ID = ku.KUNDE_ID " +
"and ku.KUNDE_NAME = '" + username +"' " +
"and ku.KUNDE_PASSWORD = '" + password +"'";

kunde_id = "SELECT kunde_id FROM kunde WHERE KUNDE_NAME ='" + username + "'";
String test = "SELECT * FROM kunde WHERE KUNDE_NAME ='" + username + "'";
kontostand = "Select betrag From Transaktion Where Konto_id = '" + kunde_id + "'";
```

Comment: Still got the RuntimeException .-.

Comment: Also you are missing a ' in your last query:

Comment: This is why I don't get it! Where could be something wrong?